# mongod binary path is not obtained by "db.serverStatus().process" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, nosql

I am unable to get mongod binary path using "db.serverStatus().process" on Ubuntu 20.04.
I need to incorporate this command in a script. But "db.serverStatus().process" gives just 'mongod' as output. In Windows it gives exact path. I even included binary path in PATH environment variable and verified the path (echo $PATH).I tried using exact mongo shell path in the mongodb connect string yet same result(not simply mongo --host --port)

Comment: Why do you need the mongod binary path? According to [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#mongodb-serverstatus-serverstatus.process) output `mongos` or `mongod` is the desired value, i.e. the value on Windows is actually wrong.

Comment: Hi  @Wernfried Domscheit  
Thanks for the update. I know <systemctl status mongod> gives exact mongod binary path. But I want similar one using mongodb commands. Is there a way to achieve it.

Comment: Try `db.serverCmdLineOpts().argv`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @wernfried-domscheit. It is a good one.
Output of "db.serverCmdLineOpts().argv"

> db.serverCmdLineOpts().argv

```
[ "/mongo/4.4.22/bin/mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongod.conf" ]
```

I slightly modified it. Now it is giving what is required.
I am just accessing [0] element from the Array which is the exact 'mongod' binary path.

Output of "db.serverCmdLineOpts().argv[0]"

> db.serverCmdLineOpts().argv[0]

```
/mongo/4.4.22/bin/mongod
```